# API returning 401 on Azure but not when run locally

Tags: azure, .net-core, jwt

The application in question is a web site which has an API tacked on the side that reuses the many of the data access methods developed for the website. So there maybe some interference between the web site authentication/authorization and the API's. But if that was the case I don't understand why it works locally.

When I run locally, I can test the API using Swagger or Postman to login, get the Bearer token and use it to call the API methods. On Azure, although the login succeeds the next call to the API returns a 401:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

The most obvious difference is the appsettings.json which I've copied to the Application Configuration blade on Azure:

[image]

The original appsettings looked like:

```
  "Rt5": {
    "BaseAddress": "https://localhost:44357"
  },
  "Azure": {
    "BuildNumber": ""
  },
  "AuthentificationJWT": {
    "Audience": "ddt-ssp",
    "Issuer": "ddt-rt5",
    "SecurityKey": "not so secret"
  },
```

Usage - ConfigureServices():

```
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Unauthorized";
                options.LoginPath = "/User/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/User/Logout";
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["AuthentificationJWT:SecurityKey"])),
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["AuthentificationJWT:Issuer"],
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["AuthentificationJWT:Audience"],
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidAlgorithms = new HashSet<string> { SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256 },
                    ValidTypes = new HashSet<string> { "JWT" }
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(o =>
        {
            o.AddPolicy(AllowViewExceptions.Policy, p
                => p.Requirements.Add(new AllowViewExceptions.Requirement()));
            o.AddPolicy(AllowSubmitException.Policy, p
                => p.Requirements.Add(new AllowSubmitException.Requirement()));
        });
```

Usage - Configure():

```
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        if (UseSwagger)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1"); });
        }

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Confession: this isn't my code and I'm sure why we have the Cookie stuff mentioned though is does seem to be offer an alternative authorization mechanism. See here:

```
    public string GetAuthorization()
    {
        //TODO: use ExtractSecurityToken();
        var claimToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AuthenticationConfig.AccessTokenCookieName);
        if (claimToken != null)
        {
            return $"Bearer {claimToken.Value}";
        }
        else if (_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(AuthenticationConfig.AuthorizationHeader, out var headerToken))
        {
            return headerToken;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken ExtractSecurityToken()
    {
        var accessToken = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == AuthenticationConfig.AccessTokenCookieName)?.Value;
        if (accessToken == null &&
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue(AuthenticationConfig.AuthorizationHeader, out var value))
        {
            accessToken = value.ToString().Replace("Bearer ", ""); // TODO: Find a better way then extracting Bearer e.g Get token without scheme
        }

        if (accessToken == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (JwtSecurityToken)new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadToken(accessToken);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the problem was caused by the bizarre architecture surround the application. The Access Token value (including the SHA256 checksum calculated using the security key) was being generated in another application and passed to this one to use for its communications.

When run localling both applications were using a security key stored in their appsettings.json file and were the same.  The pipeline which deployed these applications to Azure was substituting security keys for random values and so they differed.

I've left the question here undeleted because Suryasri's link may help others later.

Answer (score 0):

- The problem appears to be with Azure Websites' "Authentication / Authorization" option, which when enabled prevents the Web Api from accepting requests with the Authentication header. Disabling the option and using the Owin library with Azure AD provides the desired solution.
- Every app service that is associated with Azure-AD has a corresponding Azure-AD application declaration of type Web app/API. This resource id is the "App ID URI" in the app service's Azure-AD application declaration.
- To debug Authentication issues, please refer this [msdn link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dd0df41b-4f00-4e5b-8688-dd4694c27e8c/getting-a-http-401-error-when-trying-to-use-my-web-api?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: Apologies to Suryasri and any others who may have wasted their time here. All I can say is I inherited this design and my punishment will be to go on having to maintain and update it.